# How to store the state of a page between reloads?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, refresh, reload

I have a website that loads its content by the user clicking a button, then the clicks calls a javascript function that updates just the content of a central `<div>` element by changing its inner html with AJAX and jQuery.

So for example, when the visitor wants to go to my contact page, they click the contact button, and the div's content is updated to the contact form by pulling that content from an external file and using it to replace the div's `innerHTML`. The actual address of the entire page doesnt change, as the entire page isnt being reloaded, just the `innerHTML` of the div.

Further to this, my site uses PHP, and I've coded it such that various content can be populated in the div on page load by passing variables in the url. For example, `index.php?page=home` will tell the PHP script to load the home page content from an external file, while `index.php?page=contact` will load the contact form. This way search engines can find each page and their content by following these links in my sitemap.

My problem is that if a visitor clicks a button and loads different content into the div, then clicks the reload button of their browser or presses CTRL+R, the entire page reloads and the div of course reverts to its original content.

My question is, is there a way to load a particular page when the browser refreshes? For example, if the visitor has loaded the page `index.php?page=home` then clicked on the contact button and updated the div content, then pressed the refresh button of their browser, can i somehow write a script that will load `index.php?page=contact` instead, preserving the look of the page and the content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Option 1: location.hash

*Easier, but not as robust. Worth taking a look at, but if you want to store the states of multiple elements, you probably want **option 2**.*

[**Here's a demonstration of the code below.**](http://jsfiddle.net/tPZuS/)

**Example:**

```
function onHashChange() {
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    // Load the appropriate content based on the hash.
}

$(window).on('hashchange', onHashChange);
$(document).on('load', onHashChange);

$('#button').click(function(){
    window.location.hash = "home";
});
```

This way, all you need to do is change the hash on button change and handle the page load using the `hashchange` event.

---

## Option 2: History API using History.js

*A little harder to implement (but not much!), but infinitely more robust. Relies on a widely used framework.*

Another, and perhaps a cleaner way of doing this would be to use the History API. It allows you to change `window.location` without refreshing the page, allowing you to handle those changes using JavaScript.

Not all browsers support the API yet though, but you could use [History.js](https://github.com/balupton/History.js/), which provides `location.hash` fallbacks if needed. [Here's a demo.](http://balupton.github.com/history.js/demo/)

**From History.js's github page:**

> History.js gracefully **supports the HTML5 History/State APIs
>   (pushState, replaceState, onPopState) in all browsers**. Including
>   continued support for data, titles, replaceState. **Supports jQuery**,
>   MooTools and Prototype. For HTML5 browsers this means that you can
>   modify the URL directly, without needing to use hashes anymore. For
>   HTML4 browsers it will revert back to using the old onhashchange
>   functionality.

**Example of History.js:**

```
function onStateChange() {
    var state = window.History.getState();
    // Handle state accordingly.

    // Fetch the data passed with pushState.
    var data = state.data;
    var title = state.title;
    var url = state.url;
}

// Check the initial state.
$('document').on('load', onStateChange);

// Listen for state changes.
window.History.Adapter.bind(window, 'statechange', onStateChange);

// Any data you want to be passed with the state change.
var stateObj = { variable : 'value' } 

// Change state using pushState()
window.History.pushState(stateObj, "State name", "/page.html");
```

The state name is ignored by most browsers. The third parameter is the bit that gets added to the URL.

Comment: Thank you for that! Very helpful. I opted for the first option as the second is at this stage a little beyond my knowledge, however I will research History.js and the history api and educate myself further upon the subject. I've used the hash idea and coded php to detect whether a hash has been submitted, what it is, and whether it's one of the acceptable pages. This works well for me because I don't use hashes for any other content. Once again, thanks! :)

Comment: sorry, i meant detect the hash with javascript. php can't detect hashes, hashes are completely client side. btw, this will work out great because it mean visitors can bookmark content more accurately.

Answer (score 0):

Weeks ago I've released a jQuery plugin for this situations, when the developer wants to add ajax content to a page, and dynamically change the URL.

The plugin is **jQuery Dynamic URL** https://github.com/promatik/jQuery-Dynamic-URL

There is a demo here: http://promatik.pt/github/dynamic-url/

---

When you load ajax content, you can **push a path** to the URL, ex:

`$.pushPath( 0 /*level*/, "contact" )`
Your site instantly turns to: `example.com/contact`

Or in your case, you can use:
`$.pushVar( "page", "contact" )`
Your site instantly turns to: `example.com/?page=contact`

This plugin also allows you to do this:
Imagine that you give me a link for: `example.com/?page=contact`

In the index page, `$.getVars( )` will return: `{"page" : "contact"}`
So with this info you can build your page based on the this queries.

There's more thigs you can do with the plugin, like listening to event onPopState (that means user went back or forward in browser, so you can rebuild your pages based on that) just try out the **[demo](http://promatik.pt/github/dynamic-url)**...

---

*Important information*: This plugin works in all modern browsers except IE9, witch works partially, you still can access url data like `example.com/?page=contact` (and build your page based on this queries) but not modify dynamically the URL during the user experience.

Comment: You should [give your plugin a namespace](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Namespacing). It's considered a bad practice to clutter the jQuery object like that.

Comment: Thanks @thordarson, that makes complete sense. I'll start doing that update tomorrow...